# Copying a file content to a variable

Tags: php

I would like to copy a php file content to a variable and execute it, not print it!
I found out that there are 2 ways:

```
file_get_contents('http://YOUR_HOST/YOUR/FILE.php');
```

In that way the code is executed but not as I want to, I will explain:

a.php:

```
<?php
require 'file.php';
$output = file_get_contents('http://example.com/b.php');
echo $output;
?>
```

b.php:

```
<?php
$hello = get_welcome_text();
echo $hello;
?>
```

When I execute file a.php I get the  Call to undefined function error, I have no idea why it doesn't recognize the require line it seems like it executes b.php separately.

The other method is:

```
file_get_contents('path/to/YOUR/FILE.php');
```

This method is just print the php script instead of executing it.

So I would like to know if there is a way to copy a php file content into a variable and execute it the same way as include/require does, and please don't suggest me to use include/require because it's not what I'm looking for. thanks!

Comment: You need to make use of `exec` to execute your PHP file.

Comment: Tried to and failed, can you expand?

Answer (score 1):

Files can *return* a value, so yes, you can use include.

`included.php`:

```
<?php
return 2 + 2;
```

`parent.php`:

```
<?php
$number = include 'included.php';
echo $number;
```

Comment: My files doesn't return values, they are actually large website pages that mixed with java script and html.

Answer (score 0):

In first 'method' server executes separare request for your file_get_contents, so no environment from calling script will be available inside it.

Use second 'method' to get contents of the script and then just eval it.

```
eval(file_get_contents('http://.../b.php.txt'));
```

File evaluated that way can define new functionality to be plugged in calling script so that you can call some method and/or pass parameters from it.

a.php

```
$r = eval(file_get_contents('http://.../b.php.txt'));
if ($r) b_foo($bar);
```

b.php

```
function b_foo($baz) {
return 42;
}
return true; // module loaded ok
```

Surely you know that executing unverified code from third parties in server context is a bad practice, but if you really need it... :)

Comment: I'm getting: eval()'d code, the code i'm trying to copy is very large and mixed with java script/html etc.. maybe because of that?

Comment: And now I'm getting failed to open stream: No such file or directory  :(

Comment: do you have an access to remote site configuration or source code?

Comment: are 'a.php' and 'b.php' on the same localhost?

Comment: Yes they are, just in seperate folders.

Comment: remove 'http:' from file_get_contents, use relative directory path, e.g. eval(file_get_contents(dirname(_ _ FILE _ _) . '/../../bla/b.php'));

Comment: That's what I did and I got the eval'd message, then I change to .phps and get the no such filke ot directory.

Comment: is 'b.php' called from other places directly? e.g. if it has '<?php in the very beginning?

Comment: b.php starts with: <section> tag. and the full error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in a.php(line number) : eval()'d code on line 1.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. Basically non-PHP text in .php file is interpreted as echo. So no matter how you eval it - it will spit that HTML to the screen. You can hack it with replacing each '<?php' with '\' + function(){ ' and each '?>' with '}() + \'', add 'return \'' to the beginning and '\';' to the end of file_get_contents, but that's just ugly and basically you're reinventing interpreter work. Refactor it, split 'b.php' to PHP code + HTML/Smarty template.

Comment: that depends on your code, I'm afraid that's too far from little question-answer site and won't be useful to other stackoverflow users. google 'separate the presentation from business logic', 'smarty template engine' or likewise